# MongoDB php $in and $regex

Tags: php, mongodb

i'm trying to combine $regex and $in to do simple search.

For example I have a user query of this kind :

```
$user_query = "for focus red";
```

In my mongodb collection for each document I have a keywords field. I want to get to get the document where the field keywords is :

```
{
    keywords :
        [0] => ford,
        [1] => focus,
        [2] => red
}
```

As you can see the user has done a mistake and typed "for" instead of "ford".

I can get the results with `$in` if the user types Ford, but I don't know how to combine `$regex` and `$in`, I have looked the mongodb doc and php mongo doc.

Comment: What is `$regex` and `$in`? Please add the related code to your question that shows more about these variables or if it's part of a mongo query, please show the query and the code related to the query.

Comment: @hakre `$in` and `$regex` are not PHP variables, they are search operators for MongoDB queries. You're asking him to answer his own question. He said he doesn't know how to write the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is my quick snippet:

```
$user_query = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ", $user_query);
$arr_query = explode(' ', $user_query);

if (count($arr_query) > 1) {
    $tmp = array();

    foreach ($arr_query as $q) {
        $tmp[] = new MongoRegex( "/". $q ."/" );
    }

    $who['keywords'] = array('$in' => $tmp);

} else {
    $who['keywords'] = new MongoRegex( "/". $user_query ."/" );
}

$db->collection->find( $who );
```

Comment: btw, you can replace $in with $all to narrow sesults

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Mongo with PHP but i would do like this: (i'm using mongo shell syntax)

```
//find everything inside test that was either written by someone or text contains the word "and"
db.test.find( { $or : [ { "keywords" : { $in: ["Ford"] } } , { "keywords" : { $regex: "for.*" } } ] } )
```

I'm sure you can translate in into the proper PHP structure.

Comment: The use of $or is interesting, however this is not my issue. THe question is about $regex, here you are only answering for one keyword not all the query.

Comment: @Flyingbeaver You can add as many keywords as needed. These are just arrays (in Mongo as well as in PHP) so you could write `$in: ["Ford", "focus", "red"]`